# Javadoc for Java EE in Netbeans not showing

Tags: java, ide, netbeans, javadoc

For all the javax* classes Netbeans says javadoc not found.  Anyone know how I can get javadoc to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the docs manually, link it to the IDE.

libraries -> properties -> select a jar -> edit -> there you go.

Answer (score 2):

Which doc should I download? jdk-6u21-docs.zip or j2eeri-1_4-doc-api.zip?

I added both zip to Tools > Java Platform > JDK1.6(Default) > Javadoc.

After cleaning %userprofile%\.netbeans\6.9\var\cache and restarting it still doesn't work.

What else should I do?

**Edit:** I have working javadoc for Java EE classes

1. I downloaded the *javadocee6.zip* from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/apis-139520.html)
2. Go to *Tools > servers > Tomcat 6.0 > Javadoc*
3. Press *Add Zip/Folder*
4. Browse for javadocee6.zip
5. Press *Close*
   It works instantly

Answer (score 0):

It's an error that appears when you set NetBeans to use its inner webkit browser. Set an external browser in preferences, first tab.